# ria service submitchanges

Tags: ria, silverlight-5.0

I'm using Silverlight with RIA services and have tabbed UI. 
Maintaining single DomainContext object. So when SubmitChanges is called on Context I want to submit the changes for that specific object only instead of submitting all changes.

So the question is how can I SubmitChanges for a EntitySet?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a stretch, but here goes.

If you are using an event to submit the changes like a submit button, you can call your service, then you can call the entity you want to want to make changes too, then add what changes you want to make to that entity.

```
public <Your Service> _context = new <Your Service>();
```

Then in the event do something like..

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        JobMarket jm = new JobMarket();

        --Do whatever changes you want, set jm equal to tab contents etc.--

        _context.JobMarkets.Add(jm);
        SubmitOperation s = _context.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

If you put breakpoints in your code, you will be able to see exactly what jm contains, and what s is adding, modifying, deleteing etc. and make changes accordingly.  Hope this helps.